# Three columns, adjust max height to the last one, hide overflow with CSS

Tags: css

I want to have a responsive three columns, 33.33% width each.
The last column is the main one, and the height of whole content cannot be higher than the last column height. However, first two columns presents list of divs with text, one by one and the height of them might be higher than third column. I want to hide an overflow of first two columns, I'm fine if some text divs won't be visible. The most challenging is to hide partially visible text divs in the bottom of content.

I made something like this:

```css
.content { width: 800px; display: table; table-layout: fixed; background-color: #fff}
.oneandtwo {width: 66.66%; display: table-cell; position: relative; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: top;}
.oneandtwocontainer {display: table; table-layout: fixed; position: absolute; }
.one, .two {width: 50%; display: table-cell; vertical-align: top;}
.third {width: 33.33%; display: table-cell; background-color: #ddd; vertical-align: top;}
.text {padding: 10px; border: 1px dotted black}
.shouldbehidden {background-color: #fca2a2 }
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="oneandtwo">
    <div class="oneandtwocontainer">
   <div class="one">
   
   <div class="text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.  </div>
      <div class="text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.  </div>
   <div class="text shouldbehidden" > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.  </div>
      <div class="text shouldbehidden"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.  </div>
   <div class="text shouldbehidden"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.  </div>
      <div class="text shouldbehidden"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.  </div>

   
   </div>
   <div class="two">
   
   <div class="text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.  </div>
      <div class="text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.  </div>
   <div class="text shouldbehidden"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.  </div>
      <div class="text shouldbehidden"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.  </div>
   <div class="text shouldbehidden"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.  </div>
      <div class="text shouldbehidden"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.  </div>



   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="third">
       <div class="text"> Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies. Curabitur et ligula. Ut molestie a, ultricies porta urna. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies. Curabitur et ligula. Ut molestie a, ultricies porta urna.  </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Height of the content is adjusting to the height of third column, thanks to position - relative / absolute and overflow:hide. However I want all the red text boxes in this example make invisible - a truncated text looks very bad.

I guess I can do this with flex layout, but don't know really how.

I know javascript can solve the problem (with jQuery outerHeight() calculation for example), but first I would like to try with pure css.

Any ideas?

Comment: when you want them to be hidden?

Comment: when col three is lower than one or two

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.one,
.two,
.three {
  width: 33.3%;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
.one,
.two {
  position: absolute;
}
.one {
  left: 0;
}
.two {
  left: 33.3%
}
.three {
  position: relative;
  left: 66.6%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="oneandtwo">
    <div class="oneandtwocontainer">
      <div class="one">

        <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.</div>
        <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.</div>
        <div class="text shouldbehidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.</div>
        <div class="text shouldbehidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.</div>
        <div class="text shouldbehidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.</div>
        <div class="text shouldbehidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.</div>


      </div>
      <div class="two">

        <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.</div>
        <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.</div>
        <div class="text shouldbehidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.</div>
        <div class="text shouldbehidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.</div>
        <div class="text shouldbehidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.</div>
        <div class="text shouldbehidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.</div>



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    <div class="text">Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies. Curabitur et ligula. Ut molestie a, ultricies porta urna. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies.
      Curabitur et ligula. Ut molestie a, ultricies porta urna.</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your css looks better, but this is not a solution - some div.text from column .one and .two are fully hidden, but one is hidden partially and content of these two divs is not fully readable. I want div.text from column one and two, which is hidden partially, make hidden fully. This is the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.content { width: 800px; display: table; table-layout: fixed; background-color: #fff}
.oneandtwo {width: 66.66%; display: table-cell; position: relative; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: top;}
.oneandtwocontainer {display: table; table-layout: fixed; position: absolute; }
.one, .two {width: 50%; display: table-cell; vertical-align: top;}
.third {width: 33.33%; display: table-cell; background-color: #ddd; vertical-align: top;}
.text {padding: 10px; border: 1px dotted black;background-color:#fff;}
.shouldbehidden ,.oneandtwo{background-color: #fca2a2 }
```

```html
<html>

<div class="content">
  <div class="oneandtwo">
    <div class="oneandtwocontainer">
         <div class="one">

            <div class="text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.  </div>
            <div class="text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.  </div>
            <div class="text shouldbehidden" > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.  </div>
            <div class="text shouldbehidden"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.  </div>
            <div class="text shouldbehidden"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.  </div>
            <div class="text shouldbehidden"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.  </div>


         </div>
         <div class="two">

            <div class="text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.  </div>
            <div class="text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.  </div>
            <div class="text shouldbehidden"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.  </div>
            <div class="text shouldbehidden"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.  </div>
            <div class="text shouldbehidden"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.  </div>
            <div class="text shouldbehidden"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis.  </div>



         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="third">
       <div class="text"> Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies. Curabitur et ligula. Ut molestie a, ultricies porta urna. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies. Curabitur et ligula. Ut molestie a, ultricies porta urna.  </div>

  </div>
</div>



</html>
```

Comment: hm, there's no difference.